# Git Submodule versions

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am working with projects that have dependencies and I was wondering, if I have a project with a submodule inside and everything is updated, but I need to check an older version of that project. When I pull that older version of my project down do I pull down its respective version of the submodule as well or will the submodule always be up to date? If anyone can give me the 411 on how submodules work and how to use them optimally within visual studios that would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't used submodules much, but I believe the state of the submodule (i.e. which commit it is checked out to) is tracked by the containing repo, so checking out an old commit in the parent will also check out an older version of the submodule.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I wanted  to make sure that was the case! Thank you!

Comment: By default, `git checkout` or `git switch` *does not* update submodules. You can turn on such updating with the "recurse" options and settings, or you can explicitly run `git submodule update`, perhaps with `--recurse` as well.

Comment: It's important to understand the mechanism here: each commit in the *superproject* contains, for each submodule, a *gitlink* entry that says "when this superproject commit is checked out, the correct submodule commit is _____" (fill in the blank with the hash ID). So the information exists. The trick is to make sure Git uses it at the right time. That's where the `git submodule update` or recursive checkout / switch options come in: to make the update happen. The updates happen by doing "detached HEAD" checkouts in each submodule.